# Azure Data Factory - Self Hosted IR

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data Factory to copy SQL data from on premise to Azure Data Lake. 
For this we have installed Self hosted IR in one of the VM in On Premise environment.

Question- The On-Prem VM (with self hosted IR) has to be kept running and incurs additional infra cost. Is there a way to use Azure IR instead for using Self Hosted IR to copy data using ADF from on prem SQL to Azure Data Lake?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to do this, unless you want to expose your onprem database to the internet (which is not recommended). If you do that then maybe you are able to connect to it via AzureIR.

Remember that it doesnt need to be a dedicated vm just to host the IR, you can use it to do other tasks while the IR is not being used.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin. So if I have a VPN Gateway connectivity between On-Prem and Cloud will the Azure IR work?

Comment: Im not entirely sure about that, as the Azure IR is not like a regular Azure Resource but I think its worth a try at least.

Comment: The Azure ir won’t work but you can install the self host on an Azure vm instead of in your on premise data centre and bring it up and down as required.

Comment: I discarded that option because he said he is trying to save money on infra costs, but yes that one will definitely work!

Answer (score 0):

- If the Integration Runtime is running on your on-premise server, it will not incur any cost within Azure.
- If your SQL Server is open to internet and will allow the Azure IR to access it (using SQL Auth) then you can definitely use Azure IR for your data copy activity, but that's usually not the case in most enterprises and so that answer is a NO.